# Wordpress shortcodes are not working

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to use shortcode in wordpress. but its not working. I am new at this kind of job.

My codes are:

```
This is a post with short code ......

[contact-form]
[contact-field label="Name" type="name" required="true" /]
[contact-field label="Email" type="email" required="true" /]
[contact-field label="Website" type="url" /]
[contact-field label="Comment" type="textarea" required="true" /]
[/contact-form]
```

But it doesn,t work. It print the code as it is. Whats wrong with my code?

[image]

Comment: Are you using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin?

Comment: You are using shortcodes in wrong way.

Comment: No. I am not using it. @WisdmLabs

Comment: Which is the correct way? @WisdmLabs 1

Comment: Please refer [Wordpress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Comment: Where is your code? Please add whatever you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging shortcode problems](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/210958/debugging-shortcode-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wordpress application (ie. from Wordpress.org) does offer some [default shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) that you can reference.

> [audio]
>   [playlist]
>   [wp_caption]
>   [caption]
>   [embed]
>   [gallery]
>   [video]

[contact] is not one of them. You seem to be referring to the Shortcodes offered by [Wordpress.com](https://en.support.wordpress.com/contact-form/) however these shortcodes are peculiar to sites hosted on Wordpress.com - they will not work in your Wordpress application.

To call other shortcodes you will need to choose a plugin that includes contact shortcodes, or write your own, as described in the [Wordpress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).